# "Regardless to the fact" vs "Regardless of the fact"

Tags: phrasing

I want to say that something will happen regardless of whether something else happens. However, in my particular situation, using *regardless of* sounds awkward.

> Some arrangements work better than others, **regardless of** the number of
>   detectors used.

Is *regardless to* a suitable replacement in this situation? Or is my first sentence fine? Are there any alternative ways of phrasing this?

> Some arrangements work better than others, **regardless to** the number of
>   detectors used.

Comment: I had to re-read the sentence four times to figure out what you thought sounded awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Regardless to" doesn't really work, I think—I understand the meaning, but *regardless* doesn't normally collocate with *to*, so it sounds odd. To my ears, there's nothing wrong with the first sentence. If you really want to avoid that doubled *of*, you could try this phrasing:

> Some arrangements work better than others, no matter how many detectors are used.

Note that this is a bit less formal than your original.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will just stick with "Regardless of" then. I think it was the fact that I said "of the number" which thew me off. I can accept "regardless of the fact", but "regardless of the number" sounded weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Regardless to" is the one that sounds awkward because it's utterly ungrammatical.

However, "regardless of", aside from being grammatically correct, sounds quite appropriate to my ear.

> Some arrangements work better than others, [**regardless of the number of**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_order_quantity)
>   detectors used.

Here's an equally formal alternative you might want to consider:

> Some arrangements work better than others, *whatever* the number of detectors used.

Answer (score -1):

I think regardless-of sounds right to most people, largely due to its common usage.

Fair enough; but when I think about it a little, regardless OF sounds a bit off, however familiar.

If you take 'regard' as a synonym for 'consideration,' then think of the phrase 'show some consideration,' [in relation to a person] then that phrase would, to my ear, sound better followed by 'to' than by 'of.' Thus:

They showed no consideration to me.

sounds better than:

They showed no consideration of me.

So, perhaps

They showed no regard to me.

is preferable to:

They showed no regard of me.

So, regardless-to is, maybe, better than regardless-of.

You might also say  'without regard to'  rather than  'without regard of'.

All academic, though. Nigh on impossible to change such ingrained linguistic habits.

Just my twopenneth  :)

Andy

Comment: *Regardless of the fact....* is a logical argument, not an address to a person; the social niceties that language affords us do not come into play here. Besides there's a long history of *regard* using *of*, even among persons, probably because regard itself is a logical concept, not a person.